# printing array from a method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

i think its printing the code from memory and not the actual array. the reason i coded it this way is everything has to be in a method. when i run it prints char instead of integers. that why i figure its from memory.

```
enter code here

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ArrayDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] numbers1 = readInputs(5);
    int[] numbers2 = createNumbers(5);
    System.out.println("System Generate Array");
    printArray1(numbers1);
    System.out.println("User Input Array");
    printArray2(numbers2);
}
public static int[] createNumbers(int numberOfOutputs)
{
    Random generator = new Random();
    int Low = 1;
    int High = 25;
    int[] outputs = new int[numberOfOutputs];
    for (int i = 0; i < outputs.length; i++)
    {                                           
        outputs[i] = generator.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;
    }
    return outputs;
}    
public static int[] readInputs(int numberOfInputs)
{
  System.out.println("Enter " + numberOfInputs + " numbers: ");
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  int[] inputs = new int[numberOfInputs];
  for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
  {
     inputs[i] = in.nextInt();
  }
  return inputs;
}
public static void printArray1(int[] list1)
{
   System.out.println(list1 + " ");
}
public static void printArray2(int[] list2)
{
    System.out.println(list2 + " ");
}
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is how to i get it to print all the values in each of the specified arrays